# How to map the Alien Command Center Buttons in the Alienware 17?

Tags: laptop, alienware, media-buttons

I need a Ubuntu specific Alienware 17 laptop driver pack, which also includes the alien Command Center Buttons programs etc?
Just got a Alienware 17 2013 with 32gig ram 3 gig video & want to get rid of windows 8, but don't want to loose all the alienware specific programs.
Has anyone tired and succeeded to install all drivers, programs etc?

Comment: +1 - would like to see a module or something for the Alienware chassis LED's, etc. There's an unmaintained project for this [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/alienware/458528-alienfx-lite-linux-windows-alienfx-tool.html).

Comment: @searchfgold6789 do you have a Alienware and do not work?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion a good way will be to use Ubuntu first without changing anything in your current configuration.

To do so you can use Bootable Ubuntu pen drive or can just use a DVD and boot your system using it and then click `Try Ubuntu`. If you are satisfied with your experience then you can go on to installation.